# create 2 identical classes of different subtype

Tags: generics, kotlin

I use an Android library that asks me to create 2 classes, 
each inheriting from a different class. 
(with a common base class)

for now I have this code:

```
class IncomingFileMVH(itemView: View):
Lib.IncomingTextMVH(itemView) {

    private val tv: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text)

    override fun onBind(message: ChatMessage) {
        super.onBind(message)
        tv.text = message.text
    }
}
```

and I have to duplicate this class to create an `OutcomingFileMVH` that extends `Lib.OutcomingTextMVH`, even if both of my classes share the exact same code.

I simplified the code for the example, but the duplication may be important.
I settled with putting my code in static methods outside of these 2 classes,
and call them in the classes overridden methods, but I think there must be a cleaner way to do this.

Could you help me with this problem?

`Lib.OutcomingTextMVH` and `Lib.IncomingTextMVH` both inherit from `Lib.BaseMVH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see one solution but it may be unefficient in case if `onBind` called a lot of times. Put this code in one file to ensure that shared logic isn't exposed anywhere else:

```
class IncomingFileMVH(itemView: View):
Lib.IncomingTextMVH(itemView) {

    override fun onBind(message: ChatMessage) {
        super.onBind(message)
        bind(message) //Import extension method from Shared
    }
}

class OutcomingFileMVH(itemView: View):
Lib.OutComingTextMVH(itemView) {

    override fun onBind(message: ChatMessage) {
        super.onBind(message)
        bind(message)
    }
}

private object Shared {

    val Lib.BaseMVH.tv: TextView
        get() = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text)

    fun Lib.BaseMVH.bind(message: ChatMessage) {
        tv.text = message.text
    }
}
```

Roughly speaking the problem here that we can't store any value in extension property. So every time when `onBind` is called it also calls `itemView.findViewById(R.id.text)`.

There is also another solution which I prefer more. Create contract interface for properties, implement it for both classes and create helper extension method for `onBind()`

```
private interface Base {

    val tv: TextView
}

class IncomingFileMVH(itemView: View):
Lib.IncomingTextMVH(itemView), Base {

    override val tv: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text)

    override fun onBind(message: ChatMessage) {
        super.onBind(message)
        bind(message)
    }
}

class OutcomingFileMVH(itemView: View):
Lib.OutComingTextMVH(itemView), Base {

    override val tv: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text)

    override fun onBind(message: ChatMessage) {
        super.onBind(message)
        bind(message)
    }
}

private fun Base.bind(message: ChatMessage) {
    tv.text = message.text
}
```

Yep, you need to duplicate all properties with `View`'s, but as before all binding logic is placed into single method and **all properties initialized once**.

Comment: Thank you, I tried a bit with the interface solution, but didn't found the variable override thing before.